# PERL RRDTTOL: graph subroutine with conditional legend

Tags: perl, rrdtool

Stupid thing I can't manage...

in Perl, with RRDTool (rrds module), I create a common subroutine to create the graphs for the different time period (1 day, 1 week,...).
I want to use some sub argument to also display optional legend.

With the following code, that does not generate any graph....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use OWNet;
use RRDs;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $rrd = '/var/rrd/electricite.rrd';
my $img = '/mnt/ds211/web/';

&CreateGraph("conso","Consommation electrique 1 heure","1h",1);

sub CreateGraph
# inputs:   $_[0]: sensor_rrd_name
#       $_[1]: chart title
#       $_[2]: interval period (1h,24h,7d,1m,1y,10y)
#       $_[3]: Puissance instantanee (1/0)
{
    my $temp_graph;
    $temp_graph ="\"$img$_[0]-$_[2].png\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--start=end-$_[2]\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--end=now\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--width=600\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--height=200\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--slope-mode\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--title=$_[1]\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--vertical-label=Watt\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--lower-limit=0\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"--alt-autoscale-max\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"DEF:energy=$rrd:$_[0]:AVERAGE\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"CDEF:Watt=energy,3600,*\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"LINE2:Watt#0000FF:\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"AREA:Watt#00FF00:\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"VDEF:WattHour=energy,TOTAL\",";

    if ($_[3]==1)
    {
        $temp_graph .="\"GPRINT:Watt:LAST:  Puissance instantanee\\: %6.2lf%sW\",";
    }

    $temp_graph .="\"GPRINT:WattHour:   Consommation totale\\: %6.2lf%sWh\\n\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"GPRINT:Watt:MIN:  Puissance min\\: %6.2lf%sW\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"GPRINT:Watt:AVERAGE:  Puissance moyenne\\: %6.2lf%sW\",";
    $temp_graph .="\"GPRINT:Watt:MAX:  Puissance max\\: %6.2lf%sW\"";

    RRDs::graph ("$temp_graph");

    if ($ERROR = RRDs::error)
    {
        print "$0: failed to generate graph $_[0] data into rrd: $ERROR\n";
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: unrelated but..  to save yourself from all those escaped double quotes you can specify another character as your interpolate quote mark using qq - eg qq!"$img$_[0]-$_[2].png"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are handing rrdtool a string instead of an array with your arguments.

Instead of

```
RRDs::graph ("\"graph.gif\",\"DEF:...\" ...");
```

you should be calling

```
RRDs::graph ("graph.gif","DEF:...","...");`
```

if you want to prepare your arguments before hand, then you would use

```
my @args = ("graph.gif","DEF:...","...")
RRDs::graph(@args);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that the space characters in the title are throwing off option parsing. How about some single quotes around the title in your $temp_graph string?

I hope this helps.

```
my $temp_graph = qq{"$img$_[0]-$_[2].png",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--start=end-$_[2]",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--end=now",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--width=600",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--height=200",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--slope-mode",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--title='$_[1]'",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--vertical-label=Watt",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--lower-limit=0",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"--alt-autoscale-max",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"DEF:energy=$rrd:$_[0]:AVERAGE",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"CDEF:Watt=energy,3600,*",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"LINE2:Watt#0000FF:",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"AREA:Watt#00FF00:",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"VDEF:WattHour=energy,TOTAL",};

if ($_[3]==1)
{
    $temp_graph .= qq{"GPRINT:Watt:LAST:  Puissance instantanee\\: %6.2lf%sW",};
}   

$temp_graph .= qq{"GPRINT:WattHour:   Consommation totale\\: %6.2lf%sWh\\n",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"GPRINT:Watt:MIN:  Puissance min\\: %6.2lf%sW",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"GPRINT:Watt:AVERAGE:  Puissance moyenne\\: %6.2lf%sW",};
$temp_graph .= qq{"GPRINT:Watt:MAX:  Puissance max\\: %6.2lf%sW"};

print join qq{",\n"}, split /","/, $temp_graph;
print "\n";
```